# Rest API SalesOrder with Payment

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to enter a sales order with a payment against 2019R2, which from the demo's I've seen should work, however I receive a fairly useless exception message:

```
{
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "Operation failed",
    "exceptionType": "PX.Data.PXInvalidOperationException",
    "stackTrace": "   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.Put(ISystemContract systemContract, String version, String name, EntityImpl entity, CbOperationContext operationContext, Boolean throwOnError)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.SoapFacadeBase.PutImpl(EntityImpl entity, Boolean throwOnValidationError)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.SystemContracts.V2.RestController.PutEntity(EntityImpl entity, String select, String filter, String expand, String custom)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()",
    "innerException": {
        "message": "An error has occurred.",
        "exceptionMessage": "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.",
        "exceptionType": "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException",
        "stackTrace": "   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)\r\n   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityExportContextBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass87_1.<FindImplementations>b__3(PXGraph graph, EntityImpl entity, EntityImpl targetEntity)\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.ProcessCommand(SyCommand cmd, Boolean& needCommit)\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.ExportTable()",
        "innerException": {
            "message": "An error has occurred.",
            "exceptionMessage": "Inserting  'AR Payment' record raised at least one error. Please review the errors.",
            "exceptionType": "PX.Data.PXOuterException",
            "stackTrace": "   at PX.Data.PXUIFieldAttribute.CommandPreparing(PXCache sender, PXCommandPreparingEventArgs e)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnCommandPreparing(String name, Object row, Object value, PXDBOperation operation, Type table, FieldDescription& description)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXTableAttribute.PrepareParametersForInsert(PXCache sender, Object row, Type[] tables, ISqlDialect dialect, Boolean audit, List`1[] pars)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXTableAttribute.PersistInserted(PXCache sender, Object row)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistInserted(Object row, Boolean bypassInterceptor)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persist(PXDBOperation operation)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist(Type cacheType, PXDBOperation operation)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist()\r\n   at PX.Objects.AR.ARPaymentEntry.Persist()\r\n   at PX.Data.PXSave`1.<Handler>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__28.MoveNext()\r\n   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__28.MoveNext()\r\n   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.PressImpl(Boolean internalCall, Boolean externalCall)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.Press()\r\n   at PX.Objects.EndpointAdapters.DefaultEndpointImpl18.Payments_Insert(PXGraph graph, EntityImpl entity, EntityImpl targetEntity)"
        }
    }
}
```

The Following was the request made:

```
    {
    "CashAccount" : {"value" : "MERCHANT"},
    "OrderType" : {"value" : "SO"},
    "CustomerID" : {"value" : "35"},
    "CustomerOrder" : {"value" : "1"},
    "DisableAutomaticDiscountUpdate" : {"value" : true},
    "Description" : {"value" : "ecommerce order"},
    "LocationID" : {"value" : "MAIN"},
    "Details" : [
        {
            "rowNumber" : 1,
            "InventoryID" : {"value" : "item1"},
            "UnitPrice" : {"value" : 320.00},
            "SalesAcctID" : {"value" : "40200"},
            "UOM" : {"value" : "EA"},
            "OrderQty" : {"value" : "1.0000"}
        }
    ],
    "BillToContactOverride" : {"value" : true},
    "BillToContact" : {
            "rowNumber" : 1,
            "Attention" : {"value" : "Joe DiMaggio"},
            "BusinessName" : {"value" : "Major League Baseball"},
            "Email" : {"value" : "joe@baseball.fun"},
            "Phone1" : {"value" : "877-123-4567"}
    },
    "BillToAddressOverride" : {"value" : true},
    "BillToAddress" : {
            "rowNumber" : 1,
            "AddressLine1" : {"value" : "123 Main Street"},
            "AddressLine2" : {"value" : "attn: team manager"},
            "City" : {"value" : "Los Angeles"},
            "Country" : {"value" : "US"},
            "State" : {"value" : "CA"},
            "PostalCode" : {"value" : "91324"}
    },
    "ShipToContactOverride" : {"value" : true},
    "ShipToContact" : {
            "rowNumber" : 1,
            "Attention" : {"value" : "Joe DiMaggio"},
            "BusinessName" : {"value" : "Major League Baseball"},
            "Email" : {"value" : "joe@baseball.fun"},
            "Phone1" : {"value" : "877-123-4567"}
    },
    "ShipToAddressOverride" : {"value" : true},
    "ShipToAddress" : {
            "rowNumber" : 1,
            "AddressLine1" : {"value" : "123 Main Street"},
            "AddressLine2" : {"value" : "attn: team manager"},
            "City" : {"value" : "Los Angeles"},
            "Country" : {"value" : "US"},
            "State" : {"value" : "CA"},
            "PostalCode" : {"value" : "91324"}
    },
    "ShipVia" : {"value" : "FEDEXGRND"},
    "ShippingSettings" : {
            "ShippingTerms" : {"value" : "WEBORDER"},
            "ShipVia" : {"value" : "FEDEXGRND"}
    },
    "Status" : {"value" : "open"},
    "TaxTotal" : {"value" : 24.80},
    "Totals" : {
            "PremiumFreight" : {"value" : 6.00},
            "FreightTaxCategory" : {"value" : "FR020100"}
    },
    "Payments" : [{
        "AppliedToOrder" : {"value" : 326.00},
        "CashAccount" : {"value" : "MERCHANT"},
        "PaymentAmount" : {"value" : 326.00},
        "DocType" : {"value" : "Prepayment"},
        "PaymentMethod" : {"value" : "CC"},
        "PaymentRef" : {"value" : "12345"}
    }]
}
```

The Order is successfully entered when I submit this, however the payment is not.  Tried various combinations in the Payments field.  I know one suggestion is to get a sales order record and use $expand to get the sub data, however adding Payments to $expand does not work, it returns an empty array, even on order which have payments recorded.

I've tried several combinations in the Payments array, tried recording multiple payments at the same time, tried not applying the payments, or applying only $1.  Tried Payment and Prepayment doctypes.  The only thing that works is if I pre-enter a payment I can use that payment's ReferenceNbr to apply an amount to the order, however that isn't what is described in the documentation or video demo I've seen.

Anyone have an real life working example of this?  I'd prefer the enter ecommerce transactions in a single request, and not have to use 2 requests to enter sales order then payment.

Comment: Try using the Profiler built into Acumatica so that you can get more details on the error.

Comment: As a test, can you see if in your payment method was the checkbox "AR - Suggest Next Number" checked?  This will populate the PaymentRef field which is required.  I know you want to populate that field but curious if that resolves the error.